# Как сделать ссылку на номер телефона в телеграм?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Есть телеграм бот на node.js.

На одну из команд он должен выводить список номеров:

```
bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Якщо ви потребуєте допомоги – звертайтеся за одним із цих номерів:\n\n"+
                        "• [0 800 60 20 19](tel:+380800602019)– контакт - центр МОЗ.\n\n" +
                        "• 1547 – урядова лінія.\n\n" +
                        "• 0 800 33 20 29 – лінія підтримки для ветеранів та членів їхніх родин Українського ветеранського фонду(працює цілодобово).\n\n" +
                        "• 0 800 100 102 – лінія Національної психологічної асоціації.\n\n" +
                        "Усі консультації надаються анонімно та конфіденційно.",
                        { parse_mode: 'Markdown' })
})
```

Оно выводит номера, но без ссылок на номер. Как я понял телеграм сам определяет номер и сам делает ссылку.

Как можно повесить на номер ссылку, чтобы эта ссылка открывала этот номер в наборе номеров? возможно какой-то внешний сервис?